# What kind of ladder on slope?

Tags: ladder, slope

I want to be able reach the eaves for cleaning. The ground is on a slope.  What would be a good way to get up there?  What it to be safe, not cost a fortune.  I don't need to go up very often. Adjustable ladder legs seem to be costly.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With a solid surface like that, that is sloped a little bit, a few sizable scraps of plywood or short piece(s) of 2X8 under one side is all that would require. I know it sounds sketchy if you haven't tried it, but with a solid sidewalk under it, it will be surprisingly stable. On job sites, I have used rocks, brick, 2X4, anything to get the leg even with the other. Of course discretion is used how these are placed.

If this is something you want to keep handy, a piece of 3/4" plywood, say 2 ft X 1 ft, which should be enough to comfortably set a ladder on, and fasten wood blocks on the underside, one at the low edge and another in the center that are 1ft long as well to level the plywood  "base" for the ladder to set on. You can hang it on the garage wall until needed again.

Comment: I _never_ get a ladder set up _anywhere_ around my house without propping at least one leg on a scrap of plywood, 2x4, brick or cinder block. Our ground just isn't smooth anywhere, so every ladder setup rocks unless something is shimmed.

Answer (score 0):

There are now ladders available with individually adjustable legs, or at least these adjusting legs are available as an optional addition.

I have a "22 foot" articulating ladder (folds to about 5'7") made by a name manufacturer and bought from a big box store. It doesn't have separately adjustable legs, but I think it would be a useful addition. When you are setting up on an uneven surface there is a tendency to proceed even if the ladder is leaning more than one would like and more than is safe. Of course, a clever and convenient adjusting mechanism could begin to fail as it ages and wears. The proper use of 2 x 8 might be more secure if less convenient, but a convenient safety feature is one that is more likely to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out a couple of ladder stabilisers. The first was bigger heavier and moderately expensive. Did not work hardly at all.

The second one is smaller, lighter, took five minutes to set up and works just great.  [Werner ladder stabiliser](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/building-supplies/ladders/ladder-accessories/10508?store=04484&gclid=Cj0KCQjwmuiTBhDoARIsAPiv6L922YK1FXK-gnYcsDPoSdmnv1ibnGpiZ20u-GeEJH-k6t547NpqW5MaAscpEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

[image]

I am waiting for ladder jack/steps to arrive and add to the "safety" equation .   I have 23 feet vertical to do (significant) work on the upper second floor and a quite challenging backyard with a narrow spit of land before a meter drop-off. But the steps may not even be necessary given how well the stabiliser locks in the ladder. it *really* does not want to budge.

Comment: I agree that these ladder stabilizers are a good idea, _especially_ when you have to work at a window (as in the picture). However, the OP is asking about putting the ladder on sloped ground that runs across the direction of the ladder, not stabilizing it against the wall.